# find the values of $z$ that satisfy the equality

Tags: complex-analysis

show that $ | e^{-2z} | < 1  $ if  $ Re $ $\ (z ) >0 $

b) for what values of $z $ does $ | e^{z^2} | = e^{{| z | }^{2 }}= ?$

Let $z=a+bi$, then we have $\left |{e^{a+bi}}\right | = e^a$, so solving $\left |{e^{-2(a+bi)}}\right |=e^{-2a} <1 \Longleftrightarrow{-2a<\ln (1)}\Longleftrightarrow{a>0}$

Let $z=a+bi$, then $z^2=a^2+2abi-b^2$
On the one hand we have that $| e^{z^2} | = e^{Re(z^2)}=e^{a^2-b^2}$
On the other we have that $e^{| z | ^2 } =e^{a^2+b^2}$

What are the values that meet the request? I need help on this part please

Comment: I don't quite understand where you are stuck.It seems that you have solved everything

Comment: $\operatorname{Im}(z)=0,\;$i.e., $z\in{\mathbb R}.$

Comment: How do I show what are the desired values that satisfy an equation? help with this step please